# reading a json in Javascript but it always gives 'undefined'

Tags: javascript

I am sending a Json to my javascript .

```
        myMethod(String json) {          
        alert(json);
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(json);
        alert(jsonObject);
var myResponseResult = jsonObject.result;
var myResponseCount = jsonObject.count;
}
```

It displays the json as

```
                {"Test":"123", "Test2":"234"}
```

But it displays the jsonObject   as

```
                [object Object]
```

and displays jsonObject.result   as 'undefined'

Please guide me where i'm wrong ..

thanks

Comment: Have you tried console.log() instead of alert? It will allow you to see what's going on in your object. Usually console log is better practice anyways as it is non disruptive and shows more information.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alert can only display Strings. When you pass it an object, it doesn't know what to do with it, so it just displays [object Object]

Try this:

```
alert({foo: 'bar'})
```

It should show [object Object].

The object that JSON.parse returned hss 2 keys, Test, and Test2. There is no key called result, so jsonObject.result is undefined. Try:

```
alert(jsonObject.Test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result data is an object. so to read the json try

```
var obj=JSON.parse('{"Test":"123", "Test2":"234"}')
alert(obj.Test)
```

Or you could use JSON.stringify to view the entire json object as a string.

```
alert(JSON.stringify({"Test":"123", "Test2":"234"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you don't have `result`in your `jsonObject`. Instead, you have `Test` and `Test2`.
So, try calling this function like this:

`myMethod('{"result":"123", "count":"234"}')`

As for `[object Object]` - it is normal behaviour. If you want to see the object's content, you should use `console.dir(jsonObject);` instead of `alert(jsonObject);`, then open console (F12 in Chrome) and see the result.

P.S. Javascript is weak-typed language, so you should not define type of the parameter, so you should remove the word `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var _Result = JSON.parse(response);
var _Test1 = _Result[0].Test;
var _Test2 = _Result[0].Test
```

You should define which index of your JSON data you want to be displayed or alerted.even if you have 1 record.